# does someone know what are the parameters in the Entry constructor in ikvStockChart? "entrySet.addEntry(new Entry(?));"

Tags: android, charts, stock

I am in dire need of a stock chart to be put in my android application and I literally tried all the libraries including (MPCHart). I found this ikvChart and this seems to be exactly what I want. the only issue I am facing is that in the documentation of this library, the developer did not tell what parameters are to be put in the constructor of `EntrySet()`.
If someone has used this library, please answer my question. I really need help here

I just need to know what are the parameters of Entry constructor

```
final EntrySet entrySet = new EntrySet();
        entrySet.addEntry(new Entry(...));
```

Comment: please put a link of the library ikvChart so that people can check. Maybe that'll help you get some answers.

Comment: @MonsterBrain https://github.com/wordplat/ikvStockChart
this is the link for library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the source code of `Entry`:

https://github.com/wordplat/ikvStockChart/blob/master/ikvStockChart/src/main/java/com/wordplat/ikvstockchart/entry/Entry.java

Or one of the examples provided by the library, e.g.

https://github.com/wordplat/ikvStockChart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/wordplat/quickstart/activity/Simple_TimeLine_Example_Activity.java

Answer (score 1):

Checking the Entry.java (ref from [@Philio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55432785/3192693)) here's a google translated constructor arguments list.

```
/**
     * Customize data for K-line charts
     *
     * @param open opening price
     * @param high highest price
     * @param low lowest price
     * @param close closing price
     * @param volume amount
     * @param xLabel X-axis label
     */
     public Entry(float open, float high, float low, float close, int volume, String xLabel)
or public Entry(float close, int volume, String xLabel)
```